# Defining a task dependency inside gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to [fix a gradle plugin](https://github.com/HoldYourWaffle/gradle-todo-plugin-fixed) that checks for TODO-tags.

This plugin adds a new task (`checkTodo`) which can be used to run the checks. This task isn't running automatically, but this can be done by adding this line to your build.gradle:
`check.dependsOn checkTodo`

I want to remove the need for this line in every build.gradle that uses this plugin by declaring this dependency in the plugin itself. Is this possible?

Things I've tried:

```
static void applyTasks(final Project project) {
    TodoTask task = project.tasks.create("checkTodo", TodoTask)

    project.task('check').dependsOn(task)
    project.tasks().task('check').dependsOn(task)
    project.tasks().check
    project.getAllTasks(true).get('check').dependsOn(task)
    project.getDefaultTasks().get('check').dependsOn(task)
}
```

`project.task('check').dependsOn(task)` gives:

> Failed to apply plugin [class 'org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin']
>
> Declaring custom 'check' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle plugins is not allowed.`

The set of `project.getAllTasks(true).get(project)` doesn't contain the "check" task, and the others just give "no method found" errors.

Comment: What is the problem or error message?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that the specific (or any) `check` task may not exist at the time you apply your plugin.

To ensure the creation of all tasks (even via user code in `build.gradle`), use the `afterEvaluate` closure. Please note that this method will still fail, if no task called `check` will be created in the entire build.

```
project.afterEvaluate {
    project.tasks['check'].dependsOn task
}
```

If you want to depend on the task creation of a specific plugin (e.g. the Java plugin), use `withId` or `withPlugin` method of the project plugin manager. The given closure will be executed if and when the specific plugin is applied.

```
project.pluginManager.withPlugin('java') {
    project.tasks['check'].dependsOn task
}
```